# large set of data insert using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having two tables in my php project. The first table's primary key will be the foreign key of another table. I've one form in which i've to select the start date, end date, start time, end time and amount field. When user clicks on submit button then i've to loop from start date to end date and for each date the loop should be from start time and end time with 1 hours difference. The start date can be between 1 month, 1 year or more then that. Now if i am selecting start date and end date limit of 1 month i don't have any problem in inserting the records. But if i selects the date of 3 month then it is taking too much time for inserting the record in first table. And from first table inserted id i've to loop between start time and end time of that date with 1 hours difference and inserting the records in second table. Right now for inserting data in both the table i am using following code.

```
 if(!empty($datetimerangearr)){
    foreach($datetimerangearr as $datetime){
        $dateexplod = explode(" ",$datetime);
        $placedate = $dateexplod[0];
        $placetime = $dateexplod[1];
        $bookedplaceid = $opobj->getvalue("tbl_place","place_id","item_id = :item_id AND date = :date AND time = :time",array("item_id" => $productid, "date" => $placedate, "time" => $placetime));
        if($bookedplaceid == ""){
            $selplaceid = $opobj->insert("tbl_place","item_id,maxplace,place,date,time,status",":item_id,:maxplace,:place,:date,:time,:status",array("item_id" => $productid, "maxplace" => $maxplacepertour, "place" => $maxplacepertour, "date" => $placedate, "time" => $placetime, "status" => "1"));
            if(!empty($_REQUEST["checkedprice_id"])){
                $insrtflg = 0;
                foreach($_REQUEST["checkedprice_id"] as $k => $priceid){
                    if(isset($_REQUEST["showfirst"][$k][0]) && $_REQUEST["showfirst"][$k][0] != ""){
                        $showfirstopts = 1;
                    }else{
                        $showfirstopts = 0;
                    }
                    $opobj->insert("tbl_placeprice","place_id,price_id,showfirst",":place_id,:price_id,:showfirst",array("place_id" => $selplaceid, "price_id" => $priceid, "showfirst" => $showfirstopts));
                    $insrtflg = 1;
                }
            }
        }else{
            $placebookdflg = "1";
        }
    }
}
```

`$datetimerangearr` is an array with all the dates from start date to end date. If i am selecting start date and end date of 3 months interval then it is taking 15 or more minutes to insert the record.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. Please rephrase.

Comment: First, I would debug how many queries a time period insert create. Then consider using a different ORM that allows you to insert to both parents and children or a lighter one such as RedBeanPHP. Better yet, why not do pure sql so that you can combine your inserts into a single query.

Comment: i can't combine in single query because first table inserted id i've to insert in another table as foreign key. There may be records for one month, 3 month, 6 month or 1 year

Comment: Do you have an index on the fields item_id, date and time for tbl_place?  This might help a lot.